# How can I redirect to a component and set an initial state using redux and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that has a html button that when clicked on needs to add a string to an array in a redux reducer and then redirect and render another component initializing it with this state with passed in from the original component. When I click the button it get the correct string I want and console.log(pro) I get the string from the original component I'm setting the state from and I need to initialize the state of the member component with this screen but the page doesn't load. The component I'm using works when I hard code the string in and redirect with the route in the same way.

The original component looks like this

```
const Posts = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const getProfile = async (member) => {
    const addr = await dispatch({ type: 'ADD_MEMBER', response: member })
    console.log(member)
  props.history.push('/member'
  );

  const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)

  return (
      <div>
        {socialNetworkContract.posts.map((p, index) => {
          return <tr key={index}>
    <button onClick={() => getProfile(p.publisher)}>Profile</button>
        </tr>})}
      </div>
  )
}

export default Posts;
```

The component I'm trying to render is

```
const Member = (props)=> {  
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const { state } = props.location;
  //const { state } = props.history.location;

// update user state when route state updates
useEffect(() => {
  if (state && state.user) {
    setUser(state.user);
  }
}, [state]);

// run effect when user state updates
useEffect(() => {
  const doEffects = async () => {
    try {
    


  const socialNetworkContract = useSelector((state) => state.socialNetworkContract)

  useEffect(async()=>{
    try {
     await setUser(state.user)
            console.log(user)
            console.log(user)
      const pro = socialNetworkContract.members[0]
        console.log(pro)
      const p = await incidentsInstance.usersProfile(pro, { from: accounts[0] });
      const a = await snInstance.getUsersPosts(pro, { from: accounts[0] });


    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }

  doEffects();
}, [user]);
```

The route looks like this

Even though it compiles in my terminal without an error when I click on the button I get this error in my browser.

```
src/components/posts/posts.js:69
  66 | const getProfile = async (member) => {
  67 |   const addr = await dispatch({ type: 'ADD_MEMBER', response: member })
  68 |   console.log(member)
> 69 | props.history.push('/member'
     | ^  70 | //{
  71 |  // pathname: '/member',
  72 | //  state: {
View compiled
```

This is my routes.js file

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/posts" exact component={Posts} />
      <Route path="/member" exact component={Member} /> 
        <Redirect exact to="/" />
      </Switch>
  )
}

export default Routes
```

Comment: In the first dispatch to 'ADD_MEMBER' I'm guessing you have a reducer receiving that. Note you don't need async for dispatching a static value. In your 2nd component you are collecting the state from history, not your reducer. Also looks like you have an error in your code with useEffect inside useEffect.

Comment: props.history.push('/member'); history is something you pass to Posts right? Can i see how you call Posts cause I'm guessing you use history the wrong way.

Comment: I was told history was an inbuilt method to change the page I didn't know there is anything to pass in, I edited it with my routes.

Comment: You can get access to the history object's properties and the closest 's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

export default withRouter(Example)

Comment: I just tried export default withRouter(Posts); and I still get all the object in the console I want returned from this string but it still doesn't load